# When to use one time event listeners and why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

In some javascript libraries like jQuery and backbonejs, you have a chance to use one-time event listeners like jQuerys [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), or backbonejs's [listenToOnce](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenToOnce), that listens an event precisely once and after that the listener is removed. My question is; when to use thease listeners and why to use them at all? What is the benefit of thease?

Comment: If you try to go through the documentation provided by the jQuery and backbone you will get the correct information though.

Comment: I understand what it does, but can't understand the usage of it, ie why favor one-time -listeners over regular-ones in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

One use case is if you want to prevent (ajax) requests/events from being issued in parallel due to double clicking buttons etc. In that scenario you can use the `one` delegate and reattach it when the operation has completed.

Comment: Couldn't you just disable the button after first click if you wanted to prevent parallel requests?

Comment: Yes, you could, but that is in essence what one does for you built in.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about benefits over repeat listeners, it's about implementing the behavior that you want for your app. If you want something to be clickable once, for example, you might use `.one()`. If you want something to be clickable multiple times, you would use `.click()`. There isn't an inherent advantage, it's just a choice if that's what you want to do with an element/interface etc.

Comment: Read up the other upvoted answer may be that would help you understanding it little bit.

Comment: Huh? There are many ways to prevent ajax requests/events from being issued in parallel, and many other uses for using `one`. That is one example, not the only use case for using `one`. Why did you downvote my answer? What don't I understand exactly?

Comment: You answer "*If you want something to be clickable once you might use .one()*". The OP does however know this, and asks "*When would I want something to be clickable only once?*"

Comment: It was downvoted because it doesn't suggest any good use for `$.one()`

Comment: He asks when you might use them, and for benefits, not for specific examples. There are infinite possible examples, and none of them are "good" examples. It depends on what app is being built, and what purpose the listener serves. Maybe *you* guys should be reading the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Eg.: if you want a banner to appear only once (not to bother user experience), when the user scrolls to a specified point of the document. But i think there could be a lot more examples.

Answer (score 0):

The most common case (for me) is when I run an action and I want to be notified when it's finished. Typically you'd do it using a callback. But sometimes the API you're working with doesn't have a callback and you have to listen to events. Since I only care about the next event, I use the "listen once", mechanism.

For example is Ext-JS, you have the load event that fires everytime a store is loaded with data, but I often only need to know about the first load. I could just set a callback on the `store.load()` method call if I'm the one making the call. If I'm not, I can set the event and wait until the store is loaded (just the first time).

Answer (score 0):

After reading other persons' answers, I managed to pull some strings together, and came up with an answer:

There really are some benefits for using one-time eventlisteners. Some of the points have been mentioned earlier, but not all.

First, I personally think it's good practice that code "mimics" UI-behaviour. In this case, if your UI has a button that, say, saves something and then exits, the code behind the UI is ran precisely once (in optimal case), so it makes the code more intuitive if an event is listened only once as well.

This behaviour also makes the code less prone to errors and unwanted behaviours. Thease listeners guarantee, that no listeners are forgotten on the background listening events, when they really don't need to, or, when listening something unwanted could cause errors or loss of data for instance. Also using thease one-time listeners can prevent unwanted parallel processes if the user accidentally does something, ie clicks a button twice instead just once.

There might be also some slight performance increase, since listening events eat up some resources.